# Summing the multiplication of two case expressions

Tags: mysql, sql, case

Hi I'm working on a project where I want to sum some values depending on other attributes in the table and it's associations. So far I have:

```
  SELECT (
    SUM(
      (CASE WHEN models.type = 'type_1' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END) *
      (CASE WHEN models.currency_id = other_models.currency_id THEN ROUND(models.amount * other_models.conversion, 2) ELSE models.amount END)
    ) AS difference
  )
```

but this gives me a syntax error, but I'm not sure why? Any help would be great.

Comment: and the syntax error is?

Comment: It doesn't say, it just says `check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use`

Comment: The error message should say near which part of the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that you have other columns in the `SELECT`.  There is no need for parentheses around the entire expression:

```
SELECT SUM((CASE WHEN models.type = 'type_1' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END) *
           (CASE WHEN models.currency_id = other_models.currency_id THEN ROUND(models.amount * other_models.conversion, 2) ELSE models.amount END)
          ) AS difference
```

I see nothing obviously wrong in the expression itself.